# Are all queues in Java thread-safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, queue

There exists many queue implementations in Java like LinkedList, BlockingQueues. Are all of them thread-safe? If your answer no, which implementations support concurrent access and which gives the best performance?

Note: I'm using JDK 1.6.

Comment: When you read the Javadocs of the respective classes, what exactly confused you in their wording?

Comment: why dont you read the javadoc? do you expect that we will read it for you, and post a summary here?

Comment: read the documenation, its all there )from LinkedList documentation "...Note that this implementation is not synchronized....").

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a documentation reading service. The Javadocs for each implementation tell you *explicitly* what you are asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most standard collections are not thread safe. You find this information when reading the API documention.

For example the documentation of [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally

For collections that are accessed from multiple threads you should look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package

Answer (score 7):

No. `LinkedList` for example is not thread-safe.

Those in the `java.util.concurrent` packages are thread-safe.

The best performance depends on what you do with them. And you don't choose an implementation based on its performance, but based on how the queue behaves, and what you need to do with the queue. For example, a `SynchronousQueue` has a completely different behavior from a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Comment: But when I modify a not threadsafe collection in multiple threads, and the corresponding codesection is surrounden by the synchronized(this) this also forces the application to behave threadsafe, right ?

Comment: No, that is not sufficient. All the read accesses must also be synchronized. All the iterations on the queue must also be synchronized.

Comment: sure, lets say, any accessing/mutating surrounded by synchronized(this). Better ?

Comment: Yes, that would be thread-safe, provided you never forget to do it. Encapsulating the queues in a thread-safe object, or using a thread-safe queue from the beginning would be much less fragile.

Comment: So, indeed, this is good. Because I have a own table class which inherits from ArrayList and implements Delayed in order to be added to a DelayedQueue. What changes would be necessary to use a thread-safe collection as superclass in this case ?

Comment: `Those in the java.util.concurrent packages are thread-safe.` Wrong! Only classes whose names begin with `Concurrent` are thread-safe. For example, `DelayQueue` is not thread-safe (but is in the package you mentioned) whereas `ConcurrentHashMap` is. Please see the [package Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) for more information.

Comment: @Gili care to share a reference? All classes in concurrent are intended to be used in a concurrent context. CopyOnWriteArrayList for example is clearly thread-safe, and doesn't start by Concurrent. A DelayQueue is a blocking queue. How could it be not thread-safe? The doc says "The "Concurrent" prefix used with some classes in this package is a shorthand indicating several differences from similar "synchronized" classes". It also says "The methods of all classes in java.util.concurrent and its subpackages extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization".

Comment: @JBNizet, I stand corrected but I am still uncomfortable at the thought that neither the package Javadoc nor the Javadoc for `DelayQueue` explicitly state they are thread-safe. Other classes do, but the latter does not. Most of the literature I've read indicates that you should never assume an implementation is thread-safe unless the Javadoc explicitly states it is.

Comment: The javadoc of BlockingQueue, which DelayQueue implements, says: "BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe."